# How to stop preg_replace() returning numerical references?

Tags: php, regex

I'm using `preg_replace()` to perform a regular expression search and replace.

```
$string = "This isn't my real string but it is a good example.";
$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
echo $result; // This isn&#8217;t my real string but it is a good example.
```

As you can see, `$string` contains a single quote. Regardless of whether a match is found, when I output the return value of `preg_replace()`, my single quote becomes `&#8217;`

How can I stop `preg_replace()` returning numerical references such as `&#8217;`? I need my string to keep the single quote character.

**Update**

Here's my pattern:

```
$pattern = '/#(\w+)/';
```

**Update 2**

Here's my replacement string:

```
$replacement = '<a href="https://example.com/tag/$1/">#$1</a>';
```

Comment: `&#8217;` is the decimal entity for the single quote. `preg_replace` won't change that on its own.

Comment: preg_replace will not change a string in any way other than how you tell it to.... it will not automagically convert characters to html entities

Comment: `preg_replace` function don't replace symbols by mnemonics. Please show you `$pattern` variable value. Maybe something else replace symbols to it's mnemonics. **General advice**
If you working with some big code and got strange results (thinking as compiler/interpreter bug, some famous lib/framework bug) **always** create minimal working code that demonstrates problem. If we try your code from first post we can't get results that you describe. (PHP 7.1) As a variant you can describe you PHP version, OS and so on. But I think that problem is - environment.

Comment: Try your code in a console, I believe the conversion happens when the response is being sent through a web server OR treated by a template engine.

Comment: In your example string there is no `#`... So `#(\w+)` will match nothing and no replacement will occur.

Comment: @chris85 and MarkBaker thanks for your thoughts. I just tried in the console and my single quote remains. As Axalix pointed out, the conversion must be happening elsewhere.

Comment: Check for `htmlentities` in your code.

Comment: What is `$replacement` and what are you trying to do with this code, perhaps the string is already the entity and your regex is double encoding the entity?

Comment: Also, the code is for `’`, not for `'`. You must use `'/#(\w+)/u'` as a pattern, with a `u` modifier.

Comment: @chris85 please see my 2nd update for `$replacement`. I'm just trying to replace hashtag prefixed words with links.

Comment: A real example would be good, with the source code, before and after. You could try ignoring entities, https://regex101.com/r/9WNhK3/2/. For `u` see http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php.

Comment: @henrywright `u` modifier makes the regex engine treat input as a Unicode string and the pattern will become Unicode-aware. See [SO regex docs](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/5138/regex-modifiers-flags/18161/unicode-modifier).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've updated my pattern although the u modifier didn't solve the issue in this case.

Comment: @chris85 Thanks for the example. I'm noticing it works so the culprit could be elsewhere in my system? Maybe the template engine?

Comment: There must something like `htmlentities` in your code.

Comment: Yes, I'd guess you are converting to entities somewhere.

Comment: Interestingly, when I replace `\w` with `[a-zA-Z]`, the problem disappears. Very odd.

Comment: I still think there's something going on internally with `preg_replace()`. Even though it doesn't output html entities, my guess is it does the conversion internally before converting back and returning a value.

Comment: @henrywright - preg_replace() will not be doing any html entity conversion internally; it is completely html-agnostic; it works purely with bytes and characters, and has no knowledge even of the existence of html

Comment: @henrywright `\w` is `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, and `_`s. The `[a-zA-Z]` alone won't match the `0-9` so your entity, `&#8217;`, is not matched. With the `#\w+` you match `#8217`.

Comment: Exactly @chris85. My thinking is `#\w+` matching `#8217` could be the source of the problem.

Answer (score -1):

you can try using [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) to achieve that

here is a snippet

```
$string = "This isn't my real string but it is a good example.";
$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
echo html_entity_decode($result); // This isn't my real string but it is a good example.
```